# Download sqlite file stored in s3 bucket through node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a sqlite file stored in S3 bucket. I want to download it in the my local machine or directly access it. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your S3 bucket in your local machine. https://code.google.com/archive/p/s3fs/wikis/InstallationNotes.wiki

But why would you want to do that, if you are just going to read data from your setup this setup will work fine, but if you are going to write data back to it via multiple channels, each channel will use a copy of the file and you will lose concurrency.

The best way will be to clone it to an EBS and write a script to back it up to S3 as a sqlite file.

Comment: Using s3fs with a sqlite database would have a net result far worse than "losing" concurrency.  Remembering that S3 is an object store -- no append or modify functionality, only complete overwrites, just to flip a single bit anywhere in the file, eventual consistency, and no object-level (much less block or byte-level) locks -- that and s3fs is an attempt to biild an impedance bridge between that and filesystem semantics... this setup would only result in an eventually but thoroughly mangled file, due not to any component flaws but rather to a complete lack of suitability of tools-to-task.